# What is an estimator?

Tags: parameter-estimation

If $p_y$ is a probability function for a density, which depends on the value of $y$ (for example, $y$ might be the mean in the poisson distribution).

Assuming that $y$ is random -- i.e. unknown -- how would one estimate the probability that $X < x$ for $X$ being distributed with $p_y$ as the probability function?

My approach so far has been to just generate a large set of $y$ and then using those values to generate an equally large sets of $X$ and then counting the number of values less than $x$.

Would/could this be considered a classic estimator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at, basically, is the [empirical distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function). This is a very classical thing.

According to [the law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), you will eventually end up with very good estimates for $P(X < x)$. Further, by [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), your estimator for this probability is asymptotically normal. There is also [a result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem) on the uniformity of the convergence and [other results](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2236265?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) related to testing whether the underlying distribution has a specific form.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that this could be considered "the" classic estimator?

Comment: For the problem of estimating $P(X < x)$, in general, sure. I can't even think of any other way of doing that, unless you have some extra information about $X$.

Comment: That's what I thought. Awesome